# url embedded paramers in @angular/http

Tags: rest, http, angular, typescript, parameters

I use an backend that acceps both search query parameters in the ?-notation and the url-embedded way. I know that i can use e.g. URLSearchParams/RequestOptionsArgs to make an request e.g. to http://mydomain/api/card?id=abc.

But how can i for example use an mor RESTish like http://mydomain/api/card/abc by for example define an url like 'card/:id' as you for example also do when defineing the applications routes?

The following snipplet is how i am for example now build an get request:

```js
public getRequest(url: string, params: URLSearchParams): Observable < Response > {
  let options: RequestOptionsArgs = {
    url: url,
    method: RequestMethod.Get,
    headers: RestService.createHeaders(),
    search: params,
    responseType: ResponseContentType.Json
  };

  let request: any = this.http.get(url, options);
  return request.map((res: any) => {
    let response = new ServerResponse(res);
    if (response.status == ServerResponseStatus.OK) return response.data;
    else console.log('ERROR: GET request ' + options + ' resulted in status:' + response.status);
  });
  //.catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`card/:id` is a syntax which says `:id` will be replaced with any number or string. So suppose you request after replacing  this is http://mydomain/api/card/abc  here `abc` is you `:id` part which keep changing.

you can simply do this.

```
  let myid='abc';

 `let url='http://mydomain/api/card/'+this.myid;` <- here id is a variable which you get as a argument. 

   let request: any = this.http.get(url, options);
          return request.map((res: any) => {
            let response = new ServerResponse(res);
            if (response.status == ServerResponseStatus.OK) return response.data;
            else console.log('ERROR: GET request ' + options + ' resulted in status:' + response.status);
          });
          //.catch(this.handleError);
        }
```

Comment: that approach ofcourse is possible. i really tried to avoid this "manual" url-building and hoped for an automated replacement like in angularjs1. There you could supply parameter names and values and the replacement was dine by the framework.

But then there is nothing like that in angularjs2?

Comment: sorry ..  i don't know much about angular 1 but in angular 2 you can create a service and pass your parameter names and values and in service it will automatically put those values to your get or post request.  you just have to pass your json to request in body like this this._http.post(api_url, JSON.stringify(body), options)          .map(this._extractData)
            .catch(this._handleError);

Answer (score 0):

you just need to pass in the url in the format you want to support, so just pass in a URL into your function that looks more like the REST url you want.

Then you just need to change your backend to understand the new URL. You do not say what technology you are using at the backend. If you are using NodeJS then I would recommend expressJS which is great at handling URL parameters and routes with the something/:id notation

Comment: my current framework is an vert.x rest verticle. vert.x is already flexible enough to understand both formats out of the box.
before that i actually used an nodejs/express backend. 
But the server is not the problem. The problem is getting angularjs2's http client to to the parameter replacement.